# @PreserveOnRefresh - Purpose and need?

Tags: java, web, annotations, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a doubt regarding the purpose of @PreserveOnRefresh annotation. What is the purpose of this particular annotation and what are the scenarios in which it has to be used? What are the effects of using/not using this annotation?

Thanks,
Daniccan VP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23613202/642706) is not quite correct as noted in the comments (summarized here).

## Vaadin 7

This Answer applies to Vaadin 7.

Vaadin 6 is different in some ways.

## Session Is On-going

As soon as a user’s browser reaches your Vaadin app, a [Servlet session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452/642706) is created. The [VaadinSession](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html) contains [a wrapper](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/WrappedSession.html) around that Servlet session, reachable via [VaadinSession.getSession()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html#getSession()).

The session continues until a time-out occurs, you explicitly close it, user quits the browser app, or other such terminating event. But the user hitting the Reload/Refresh feature is *not* such a terminating event.

## Reload/Refresh Button

While that session is on-going, the user may click/tap the Reload/Refresh icon feature in the web browser. By default this causes your current UI subclass object to be replaced by a new fresh UI subclass object.

To your user, it appears your app has restarted. But actually your app was *not* interrupted, only the content in that particular browser window/tab was discarded. Your app (your VaadinSession) lives on.

Your app may have had other browser windows/tabs open, each with their own UI subclass object. Those other windows/tabs would still be running with the same UI object. All of those running UI instances are tied to the same `VaadinSession`.

## Retain UI Object on Reload/Refresh

You may or may not want your UI subclass object discarded on a Reload/Refresh of the browser window/tab, depending on the nature of your particular app.

Do you want the user to be able to do a "do over", to start again from scratch? If so, keep this default behavior. Do not apply the annotation.

If you want to change the effect of a browser Reload/Refresh to keep the UI object and its state, apply the [`PreserveOnRefresh` annotation](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/PreserveOnRefresh.html). Easy, almost like magic.

## Two Levels Of Scope

In Vaadin 7, you may store state either at the level of a browser window/tab (a [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) instance) or app-wide (on VaadinSession).

If you want some data to survive the discarding of a [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) object, store that data on the VaadinSession by calling the get/setAttribute methods. For example, you would keep user login/authentication information on the VaadinSession.

To learn more these two levels of scope, including crucial information about thread-safety, see this other question, [how to put data in session variable and get the data in different page in vaadin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15439761/642706).

## Diagram

This diagram shows the session hierarchy. The upper three levels (Servlet Container, ServletContext, and HttpSession) are all standard Servlet technology. Below those are the Vaadin-specific levels.

[image: diagram of Servlet container, context, and session]

Comment: What happens to the components in UI with regards to their lifecycle. Will closing the browser or signing out begin the process of GC provided I have written methods for the same.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar By “GC”, do you mean garbage collection? Once the session ends then all the session-related objects (`VaadinSession`, `HTTPSession`, session attributes, `UI`, and all your Vaadin widgets in those `UI` objects) become candidates for garbage collection, unless you have inappropriately kept references to them in other objects. GC happens automatically, no need for you to “write methods”.

Answer (score 0):

When the enduser does press F5 (or click Refresh) in the web browser,
then the behaviours is:

With @PreserveOnRefresh
-> Use the same session, just refresh the UI from the server state

Without @PreserveOnRefresh
-> Vaadin is creating a new session for the user and the user is shown the "first" page of your application

So usually the @PreserveOnRefresh is the intended behaviour, otherwise the user is logged out when he clicks on refresh

Comment: Hi André, that's not quite correct. Vaadin will not create a new session for the user when the browser is refreshed. Instead, a new instance of the application's UI class is created and added to the user's session. The old UI instance goes into the background. If @PreserveOnRefresh is used, the existing UI object for the refreshed browser window will be re-used. This has the effect, that the current state of the browser window (user input, current page, etc.) will be retained, even after a refresh.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a new vaadin session, not a http session, but my description of the effects is correct

Comment: Still not quite right ;) A Vaadin session is just a wrapper around the HTTP Session. So, with a browser refresh you won't get a new Vaadin session either. It's only about whether or not a new UI instance is created by the servlet. See https://vaadin.com/api/7.1.15/com/vaadin/annotations/PreserveOnRefresh.html for reference. Without using this annotation a user will not be logged out after a refresh, unless this login information is stored in UI scope (see my blog post http://blog.oio.de/2013/02/22/vaadins-variable-scopes-vaadinsession-and-ui/ on UI and session scope in Vaadin).