# How would a user have multiple `VaadinSession` objects for a single `HttpSession`?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, httpsession

[Vaadin](https://www.Vaadin.com/) 7.2 and later offers this static method:
 [`VaadinSession.getAllSessons( javax.servlet.http.HttpSession httpSession )`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html#getAllSessions(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession))

The doc says:

> Retrieves all VaadinSessions which are stored in the given HTTP session

How does a user ever have more than one [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html) per [`HttpSession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)? Does that happen by an action performed by the user, or by me programmatically in my Vaadin app?

[image: diagram of each HttpSession object having one or more VaadinSession objects of which each has one or more UI objects]

Comment: By the way, if you find this Question interesting you may also enjoy this Question, [@PreserveOnRefresh - Purpose and need?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23612615/642706) and [my much more involved expansion](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ufjIQ.png) of the diagram seen above.

Answer (score 3):

The `VaadinSession` is always stored inside a `HttpSession`.

## Multiple Vaadin Apps In Single .war

If the deployment (a [WAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format))) contains more than one Vaadin applications ([servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)), and the user uses those applications simultaneously, then user's [`HttpSession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) contains more than one [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html) objects.

For example, a war file contains two Vaadin applications (servlet mappings), and the users is using those both in [Chrome browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), then the `HttpSession` for that user contains two `VaadinSession` objects. If those applications are deployed on separate war files, then there is a `HttpSession` for both applications and both sessions contains one `VaadinSession`.