# Vaadin Session Management - How does it work?

Tags: java, web-services, session, vaadin, vaadin8

At work, we develop a web application using Vaadin. I am a pretty advanced programmer in Java. I’m experienced with Vaadin as well. But now I've come to a point where information needs to be stored in a user session. Attributes like Locale, Username and so on.

In the [Vaadin Documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/application/application-lifecycle.html) they are talking about two different types of sessions but I dont really get the difference:

- [VaadinServletService](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServletService.html) or VaadinPortletService described as low-level customization layer for processing requests.
- [VaadinSession](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html) of a UI with getSession() as lower-level session objects.

What is the difference and which one is to use when I want so store attributes during the whole UI independent user-session?

Comment: I think `VaadinSession` is what you need. It corresponds to one user. Each `VaadinSession` can have multiple `UI`s associated (e.g. multiple browser tabs).

Comment: @SteffenHarbich thanks for your hint Steffen. Its weird but in the meantime we implemented it using VaadinServletService and it all works as it should. I cant explain why.

Comment: Please take more care with your typing (case, punctuation). This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, not a casual chat site.

Comment: Are you using Vaadin 8? You tagged it so. I suggest adding a mention within your Question body as well, as there is a huge difference between Vaadin 8 and later.

Comment: Related Question page: [*Register session to User*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58592794/642706)

Answer (score 3):

If in Vaadin 8, you have simple hierarchy of scope, on three levels.

- [ServletContext](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)
  Represents your entire Vaadin web app.
- [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.6/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html)
  Represents each user's work session.
- [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.6/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#getCustomAttributes--)
  Represents each web browser/tab within a session (Vaadin supports multi-window apps, pretty amazing).

The first is a standard part of every [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet), defined in the spec.

The second is a wrapper around the session, also defined in the Java Servlet spec.

Vaadin is actually one huge Servlet, so it carries these features of context and session.

The [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.6/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) class is unique to Vaadin. It represents the content of a web browser window/tab. Vaadin supports multi-window apps, tracking all the open windows/tabs as part of the session, a very nice feature of Vaadin.

To store state-wide app, use the standard `ServletContext` object. It carries a key-value collection known as "attributes". The key is of `String` type, and the value is of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) type. Call methods `setAttribute`, `getAttribute`, and `removeAttribute`. Use this collection for any objects you may need to access for any of your users, accoss their sessions. You may to learn about [`ServletContextListener`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) by the way, to hook into your web app launching and exiting.

The `VaadinSession` class carries the same kind of key-value collection, with similar "attribute" methods. Use this to track items throughout the user’s work session, across them possibly opening/colsing multiple windows/tabs of your app. For example, in the session you would store the user’s Spirit Animal choice, their avatar image, and the fact that person has been authenticated via username/password credentials.  See this page in the manual, [*Setting and reading session attributes*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/SettingAndReadingSessionAttributes.html).

If you want to store per-window settings, for something like their choice of background color or light/dark mode, store something on `UI`. Unfortunately, that class does not come with a convenient key-value store that I know of. So you'll need to add your own `Map`, or some other member variables to your `UI` subclass.

For more info, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25586487/642706) to a similar Question. I made some nifty diagrams there. That question is about Vaadin 7, but as I vaguely recall, these concepts carry over between 7 and 8.

As for [`VaadinService`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.6/com/vaadin/server/VaadinService.html) and [`VaadinServletService`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.6/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServlet.html), I have never understood exactly their role. They seem to represent various aspects of your entire Vaadin web at runtime. But neither carries a convenient key-value collection as like `VaadinSession`. (If you use Vaadin Flow, versions 10+, see `VaadinContext`, a class than does represent your entire web app, and does carry a convenient key-value collection of "attributes".)